What’s the point of a BIOS password?
I have realised that there is absolutely no point to having a password protecting your BIOS/UEFI menu!
Here are the reasons:
It is the easiest thing to “hack.”
Literally. Anyone can use a jumper and a users manual to remove any computer’s BIOS password, using the recovery key that anyone using the physical computer has access to.
You don’t even need to protect it!
Correct me if I’m wrong, but there’s nothing in the BIOS/UEFI menu that could do anything to your computer hardware or access any OS, and even secure boot is usually on by default.
You need physical hardware access to access the BIOS menu anyway.
You have to physically be using the actual computer to access the menu, at which point you’ve either broken into a building or stolen someone’s physical computer!
Please give me your opinions if you disagree, but I just really don’t see the point to the BIOS/UEFI password at all!

Cast your mind back 20+ years. Think about why they were added in the first place, and what tooling was available back then to hack them. Yes, they're a legacy thing which is not really relevant anymore, but once upon a time, they were relevant.

That is a good point but we don’t need them anymore! Thanks for your feedback.

"A control isn't perfect! We don't need it any more!" -- that's not how security works...

Most laptops don't actually have a jumper to reset the password anymore. A password is used to prevent changing the boot order of a system, into an operating system, that is not under the control of the owner of the device. By allowing insecure operating systems, those operating systems under the control of the hostile party, can be used to modify the operating system they want to access.  Why are you seeking our opinions on this matter?  We are not a discussion forum. We don't have discussions and share opinions.

@Ramhound laptops have pinouts to reset the bios password just like desktops do ... just not always given an actual jumper and you instead have to use a wire or a paperclip ... its also often buried and annoying to get to.

@CaffeineAddiction - There are countless examples of laptops, which been design in such a way, where the firmware password cannot be reset.  It can only be changed.

This question should not have been answered and should have been closed. This site does not deal in opinions, and that is clearly listed in the Help section. That said, your assumptions and "facts" are wrong. Most computers built in the past 15 or more years do not have BIOS password reset jumpers, to note just one point. As the importance of this setting changed, the security around it did as well. Even removing CMOS batteries is no longer a reliable method of clearing BIOS settings.


Anyone can use a jumper and a users manual to remove any computer’s BIOS password

First, on some motherboards it's not possible to remove BIOS password using a jumper or by removing the battery because the password is stored in flash memory. Examples here and here. However, sometimes there are ways to reset it anyway, like in the answers of the first example.
Second, a PC case can be physically locked in some box and cables routed through a small hole, so you can't access the motherboard. Or the PC may be under video surveillance (or staff supervision), so someone opening the case will be suspicious.

there’s nothing in the BIOS/UEFI menu that could do anything to your computer hardware or access any OS

I think the most important is the boot order. Secured PC should always boot from internal hard drive only. Otherwise someone can boot it from flash drive and install malware on it. Or steal data from it, which are protected by the OS or some third-party program.
If BIOS has overclocking options, someone can kill CPU or RAM by overvolting it.

You need physical hardware access to access the BIOS menu anyway

Not always. Like I said, you can have access to keyboard, but not to the motherboard, if the case is locked.

In addition to davidgo's answer (his answer popped up while I was typing mine, but did not want to discard the answer)
There is still a usercase where password protecting the BIOS is useful.
A computer that is publicly accessible where enough protection is in place that you can't do much will benefit from the BIOS being password protected.
You can have things like the USB ports etc being disabled, internet access being limited and/or running programs being restricted.
The computer being in a location where tampering is going to get noticed will ensure that someone can't pull a prank by changing bios settings, or do more damage by enabling USB ports to get that computer do things it wasn't designed for by the company that placed that computer there.
It can also be useful for parents who wants to lock down the pc for their small children. By setting both an admin password and a bios password, the parents can ensure that the child can only use the computer after they fill in the password, and they are usually not smart enough by that age to find a way to circumvent it. Clearing the password would mean the parent finds out which can lead to no computer access alltogether.
One last note on the subject. A password for BIOS access can be seen the same as having a cabinet with an extremely weak padlock on it.
You put the lock on it to show that someone should not access it, even though it can be bypassed with a paperclip. The fact that someone bypasses it makes their action questionable, and when caught can be enough to have an effect. The padlock here is not have absolute piece of mind that no one gets in, but it is there just as a sign to tell: nope, I don't want you in here.
Someone has to break their moral code and cross that line willingly, and you can enforce punishment for breaking that line.

Thank you all very much for your answers I appreciate it and I get what you mean about if the password was effective- but it still seems too easy to bypass…

If you really want to prevent someone from accessing the BIOS, you can. That's the whole point.

You are probably much more experienced about this topic than me so I’ll take your word for it. Thanks.

I've added a few paragraphs, different kind of security that is just as relevant.

There is some validity to your thinking, but you may have overlooked (at least) 2 use cases -
The first one is a way for corporate IT to put up a barrier to make it that much harder for people who don't really understand computers/don't have the ability to easily open laptop cases from making changes.
I'd argue the more important one is to do with SecureBoot/TPM/Bitlocker or similar.    A very rough overview - TPM checksums various values of elements of the system on startup and writes these to registers that can't be modified while the computer is running.  Programs like Bitlocker can then use these checksums as a passphrase/part of a passphrase to allow auto unlocking/limiting access to the system if its been tampered with.
These TPM checksums are called PCR registers. Per Which TPM PCRs does Windows seal into the BitLocker password? PCR0 attests the BIOS has not been compromised, with additional PCRs being used to check boot sequence - so having a password on the BIOS can be checked as part of TPM - and if someone has tampered with the SecureBoot process/BIOS settings, Bitlocker can require a backup key to mount.   This can be useful in having a system which can boot, ask for a login password and then decrypt the system - and if any changes - including changes to the BIOS are detected then this triggers the need for the bitlocker password to provide access to the data.
ie this can be used to frustrate/prevent theft of data which is very often more valuable then the computer.

Hmm, are you sure about this ? I thought BIOS/UEFI changes outside of resetting TPM or fiddling with SecureBoot did nothing and you would boot fine with BitLocker enabled.

according to https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/code-sample/protecting-secret-data-and-keys-using-intel-platform-trust-technology.html - **TPM platform configuration registers (PCRs) are used to protect against the scenario where an attacker alters the system boot parameters or boots to an operating system of their choice in order to access sensitive data. **     It looks like I was wrong about the specifics of PCR0 - I'll change my answer - PCR0 specifically protects against the BIOS firmware being hacked.  Other PCRs affect boot order.
